# How to pass index to function Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pass an index from a df into my function so that my function can run through all of the rows of the df and provide the output which is a int in a new column called "TDNumber'.

Here is the code

```
 def createTdnumber(onedfindex):
    header.index    
    maski = header.index < onedfindex 
    finder = header[maski]
    tdnumber = max(finder.index)
    return tdnumber

df['TDNumber'] = df.index.apply(createTdnumber())
```

as indicated below The mask should receive a number such as 227
That 227 would be one of the numbers provided by df.index.apply to the function

```
 def createTdnumber(onedfindex):
    header.index    
    maski = header.index < 227 
    finder = header[maski]
    tdnumber = max(finder.index)
    return tdnumber

df['TDNumber'] = df.index.apply(createTdnumber())
```

This code generates the error 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'apply'

For the 'Int64Index' how do I pass those numbers one at a time to my function?

```
header.index
```

my output is

```
 Int64Index([0, 226, 470, 659, 863, 1108], dtype='int64')
```

from shx2 solution when I run

```
df.index.to_series()
```

The output is:

```
1          1
2          2
3          3
4          4
5          5
6          6
7          7
8          8
9          9
227      227
228      228
229      229
230      230
471      471
472      472
473      473
474      474
475      475
476      476
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index types don't have an `apply` method, but `Series` does.

To apply a function to your index, you can convert it to a series first, using its `to_series` method:

```
df['TDNumber'] = df.index.to_series().apply(createTdnumber)
```

Comment: When I run the solution I get the error.

"createTdnumber() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given) "

I thought that with .apply I didn't need to put anything in the function parenthesis? Is there some other transformation that needs to occur?

I posted some additional information in the question

Comment: maybe try: `df['TDNumber'] = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda r: createTdnumber(r))` (@Erich)

Comment: or maybe just `df['TDNumber'] = df.index.to_series().apply(createTdnumber)` (@Erich)

Comment: race['Tdnumber'] = race.index.to_series().apply(lambda r: createTdnumber(r)) This worked @Paul H